# Pipeline sync is failing with error: "Failed to sync hook with err: Webhook creation failed with err: postHook returned error 422"

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

When I try to add my pipeline source, sync fails with the error:

> Failed to sync hook with err: Webhook creation failed for path:
> deepika/demoApp and integration: deepikaGithub with err: postHook
> returned error 422 for deepika/demoApp

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually the result of too many webhooks.  GitHub allows 20 webhooks per repository.
This can be resolved by performing following steps:

- In GitHub, go to the Settings | Webhooks tab for the relevant repository
- Delete all the failed webhooks